# Why Subdomains are not working with reCaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha

I got one reCaptcha account for my main domain zack-resto.com
I have 3 subdomains with same code base
 - dev.zack-resto.com
 - cad.zack-resto.com
 - load.zack-resto.com
reCaptcha is working on zack-resto.com and dev.zack-resto.com
Any idea of why cad.zack-resto.com and load.zack-resto.com are not working.

I already tried a dedicated reCaptcha account for cad.zack-resto.com and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I change the code from

```
$response = @file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
if ( $response === FALSE )  {
     $response["success"] = false;
} else   {
  $response = json_decode($response, true);
}

to
$ch = curl_init();
     $curlConfig = array(
         CURLOPT_URL            => "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
         CURLOPT_POST           => true,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
             'secret' => $privatekey,
             'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
             'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
         )
     );
     curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
     if($result = curl_exec($ch)){
         curl_close($ch);
         $response = json_decode($result,true);

     }else{

         $response["success"] = false;
         return false;
     }
```

So seems curl and remoteip are key to call recaptcha.
Thanks for your attention